# R Matching closest number from columns

Tags: r, matching, closest

I have a list of responses to 7 questions from a survey, each their own column, and am trying to find the response within the first 6 that is closest (numerically) to the 7th. Some won't be the exact same, so I want to create a new variable that produces the difference between the closest number in the first 6 and the 7th. The example below would produce 0.

```
s <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3)
s <- t(s)
s <- as.data.frame(s)
s
```

Any help is deeply appreciated. I apologize for not having attempted code as nothing I have tried has actually gotten close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
which.min( abs(s[1, 1:6] - s[1, 7]))
```

I'm assuming you want it generalized somehow, but you'd need to provide more info for that. Or just run it through a loop :-)

EDIT: added the loop from the comment and changed exactly 2 tiny things.

```
s <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3) 
t <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) 
p <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,2) 
s <- data.frame(s,t,p) 
k <- t(s) 
k <- as.data.frame(k) 

k$t <- NA ### need to initialize the column
for(i in 1:3){ 
    ## need to refer to each line of k when populating the t column
    k[i,]$t <- which.min(abs(k[i, 1:6] - k[i, 7])) }
```

Comment: Thank you, and you are correct that I need it more generalizable. Using some example code, I tried this loop and it is just producing the same results across all rows. 
s <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3)
t <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
p <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,2)
s <- data.frame(s,t,p)
k <- t(s)
k <- as.data.frame(k)

for(i in 1:3){
 k$t <- which.min(abs(k[i, 1:6] - k[i, 7]))
}

Comment: Edited the answer to include the loop you provided :-)